# What is the name of this connector of a rough use tablet?

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

I am working with an old tablet [XPLORE IX104](https://www.ebay.com/itm/221949977280?_ul=MX&chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkcid=28) but my question is about a connector such as this. What is the name of this connector?

[image: Connector]

I have not worked with similar devices before (only with devices with USB, ethernet connector and similars).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the target for a [spring loaded connector](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors/spring-loaded/408), consisting of an array of [pogo pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin). The individual [targets](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors/spring-loaded/408?s=N4IgjCBcoEwBxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIAzAOxhVwCsIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9JQA) and the individual [pogo pins](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/contacts/contacts-spring-loaded-pogo-pins-and-pressure/311?) are standard and easy to buy, but the entire assemblies are custom connectors.

Answer (score 1):

It is a `docking connector`.

Used in connecting the device to a cradle of some kind.

Comment: And if it really is that PC's docking connector, it's almost certainly proprietary, and the only equipment that works with it is the docking station sold _for_ that machine _by_ that machine's manufacturer.